# Is it a student 'in' or 'of' your class?

Tags: prepositions

I would like to talk about a hypothetical situation in which I am emailing my professor whose course name is 'BA.' If I want to tell my professor that I am one of his students, which of the following sentences should I use?

> Hello professor, this is a student **of** your BA course

or

> Hello, professor, this is a student **in** your BA course

Comment: Before a native speaker answers your question it is interesting to know if "on" is also possible.

Answer (score 3):

Someone is only a "student of" a broad field of study, not an individual class. If I say,

> I am a **student of** philosophy.

Then that means that I am generally interested in philosophy. It doesn't necessarily even mean that I'm pursing a formal degree in philosophy, just that it is one of my personal interests. (Aside: If I wanted to say that I was formally studying philosophy, especially as a degree major, I would say, "I am a philosophy student.")

If you are taking a class, then either **in** or **from** is appropriate:

> I am a student **in** your Ethics and Metaphysics class.
>
> I am a student **from** the Tuesday/Thursday section of your PHIL203 class.

**In** is probably more common.

To answer a question in the comments, you are never a "student **on**" a class.  You can be a "student on an exchange program" or a "student on leave," but **on** is never used with a class or a subject as the object of the preposition.